# How to INSERT into 1 table and UPDATE another table in one query

Tags: sql

I have a question on how to write a single query to insert and update. Below is the scenario. I am trying to use 1 query for the part that is enclosed in (-----)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    Ref VARCHAR(10),
    Num INT,
    [Status] VARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES ('A123', 1, 'A3'), ('A123', 2, 'A3'), ('A123', 3, 'A3'),
       ('B123', 1, 'A1'), ('B123', 2, 'A3'), 
       ('C123', 1, 'A1'), ('C123', 2, 'A2'), ('C123', 3, 'A3');

SELECT
    Ref, 
    CASE WHEN A.TotalCount = A.DenialCount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsDenial
    --CASE WHEN A.TotalCount <> A.DenialCount Then 1 else 0 end IsApproval
INTO 
    #TEMP1
FROM
    (SELECT
         Ref, COUNT(Num) TotalCount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ApprovedCount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'A2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PartialApprovalCount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'A3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DenialCount
     FROM
         #temp
     GROUP BY
         Ref) A

UPDATE A
SET A.[Status] = CASE WHEN IsDenial = 1 THEN 'A3' ELSE 'A1' END 
FROM #TEMP A
JOIN #TEMP1 B ON A.Ref = B.Ref

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1

DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to combine an insert and update statement?

Comment: I am using sql server 2016. To insert and update into the same table, I know I can use Merge statement but I am not sure what works in this case.

Comment: Sounds like you *may* want to use an `OUTPUT` clause.  This allows the output of an `UPDATE` to then be used as the input to an `INSERT` *(for example)*.  It's still essentially two statements, still two operations, but implicitly atomic *(essentially inside it's own transaction)*.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT into 1 table and UPDATE **another** table in one query"

Nope. Some DBMSes support the idea of 'upsert' but that's insert/update in a single table.

Comment: It is absolutely possible (for instance: PostgreSQL - multiple CTE + returning/SQL Server  - DML over MERGE, UPDATE OUTPUT INTO).

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the MERGE statment. However I see several issues with the SQL in your post. In short it is generally more efficient to use set theory instead of thinking of optimisations per statement.

Rather than update, why not join in the data thats inserted into temp into the second query and produce the result you require?

hint ' SELECT 'ABC' as a, '123' as b, 456 as c UNION '

Comment: I am already using the #Temp table in my second query and more over I am trying to update the #Temp table with the status. How does the update work if I join?